# Is _odepack.pyd a malware inside the installation?

Tags: enthought, malware, virus, canopy

I have installed two day ago enthought canopy 32 bit (for using python and its packages). When I run my antivirus, it found that the file:
_odepack.pyd

is a malware, specifically GEN:Variant.kazy.114716. It is inside 
...users\appdata\local\enthought\canopy32\user\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate
What is it? Is it a malware inside the installation?

Answer (score 1):

This is a false positive that has been reported previously. Make sure you update your antivirus definitions, as this often solves the problem. Otherwise, you should add the file to the whitelist in the antivirus.

The `odepack` library implements solvers for ordinary differential equations in scipy.

Comment: Given the tens of thousands of files in the Canopy / EPD package set, and the many different techniques that anti-virus programs use for detecting malware (especially searching for specific "signature" byte strings which statistically will occur at random in a large installation such as ours), there is unfortunately a small but regular number of false positive detections, especially from the free security programs.